# how to obtain circular shift matrix of this linear data?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Please consider this,

```
data=1:64; % sample data points
```

now this data can be circularly shifted by 1 unit (say right shifted) to obtain 64 shifted data sequences.

How could this 1D Matrix be circularly shifted in Matlab to obtain a final 64X64 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=1:64;
data1=ones(64);
for i=1:64
    data1(i,:)=circshift(data,[1 i]);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = toeplitz([1,64:-1:2],1:64)
```

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary `data`: use [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) for the circular shift and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to generate all shifts without loops:

```
result = data(mod(bsxfun(@plus, (0:numel(data)-1).', 0:numel(data)-1), numel(data))+1);
```